# Changing java file

Tags: java

Can I change a java file, when I'm running it on JVM, using this file?

For example: 
I run abc.java. In this program I've a textarea and I want to paste text from the text area into abc.java and save the changes. Is it possible?

Comment: java file won't go into JVM, but java bytecode does.

Answer (score 3):

3 steps:

1. modify your .java file just like you would modify a text file.
2. compile that .java file from within your already running JVM using [javax.tools compilation tools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html)
3. Instantiate your freshly compiled class using the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM runs class files (*.class) and not Java (*.java) files. To "convert" a *.java file to a *.class file it needs to be compiled firs.

So change a *.java File will not infuent the JVM in any way, because it is compleatly not interessed in.

**Only because of a totality answer**
You can write a programm (*.java) that when it is compiled an run (*.class) change its own source file (*.java) (for example changing a string by user input) compiles it (*.class), and restart it selfe with its new compiled form. **But this is defently not what you want!** One would write this kind of software only to prove that this insane idea would work.

Anyway, what you need is a way to store data, in a file or a database. (Have a look at the java.io package for file handling, and for an [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)).

Answer (score 1):

No. Maybe what you want is dynamic define classes at runtime. If so, you could choose dynamic language like Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

(new answer for updated question)

"In this program I've a textarea and I want to paste text from the text area into abc.java and save the changes."

This seems like a strange loop, self-modifying java code?

Then yes, the tools nrobey describes would be the way to go, though I agree with Ralph that it might be a bad idea.